# Center align* columns in math mode

Tags: align

How can I center align columns in math mode using `align*` or one of the similar environments? I [read](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159723/what-does-a-double-ampersand-mean-in-latex) that the columns in align environments align in the `rlrlr` pattern. How do I change this to a `ccccc` pattern?

```tex
\begin{align*}
    \dot{x}=&A&x+&B&u\\
    ...
\end{align*}
```

[image: align]

To explore, I used the tabular environment switching from text to math mode here. The result is what I'm looking for, but it doesn't seem like the optimal method:

```tex
    \begin{tabular}[7]{ccccccc}
        $\dot{x}$ & $=$ & $A$ & $x$ & $+$ & $B$ & $u$\\
        ...
    \end{tabular}
```

[image: tabular]

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278929/

Comment: It might be better to use `\underbrace` here instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `array` or `bmatrix`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{ccc}
x & f+g & r + t^{2}\\
a = b & \text{long text} & G = \Upsilon
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b = b = u & c \\
d & e & f \\
g & h & i
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why does array need to be inside the equation environment? Is array not normally a math environment?

Comment: Try it and see what happens

Answer (score 6):

Here's a way to implement the `tabular` idea you mention in your posting.

[image]

(Aside: Since `B` appears to be column vector, I will assume that `u` either is or evaluates to a scalar.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}} % col. type for binary and relational opeators

\begin{document}
\[ % start of an unnumbered display-math group
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt} % default value: 5pt
\begin{array}{cCccCcc}
\dot{x} & = & A & x & + & B & u \\[\jot]
\dot{x} & = & \begingroup \setlength\arraycolsep{5pt}
              \begin{bmatrix}
              1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
              1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
              1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
              1 & 2 & 3 & 4 
              \end{bmatrix} \endgroup
                & x & + & \begin{bmatrix}
                          1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\ 4
                          \end{bmatrix}
                            & u
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```